# Vitest - How do I assert that a flat function was called within a composable?

Tags: nuxt.js, vitest, nuxt3

I'm working with Vitest and Nuxt 3. I am trying to assert that `useHead()` was called with a given argument from inside a custom-written composable. In Vitest, you can create a spy to assert that a method was called on an object. But how do I assert that a flat function was called? `useHead()` is not a method on an object, so this won't work:

```js
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'

vi.mock('@vueuse/head')
vi.mocked(useHead).mockImplementation(vi.fn())

describe('myTest', () => {
  const expectedArgument = 'foobar'
  const spy = vi.spyOn(useHead, 'default') // or something like that?

  // Do something that would call useHead(withArgs) internally...

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(expectedArgument)
})
```

I have also tried wrapping `useHead` in a simple object, but that doesn't work either:

```js
describe('myTest', () => {
  const expectedArgument = 'foobar'
  const objectForSpying = { useHead }
  const spy = vi.spyOn(objectForSpying, 'useHead')

  // Do something that would call useHead(withArgs) internally...

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(expectedArgument)
})
```

It makes me realize I don't know how to assert that any kind of flat function was called anywhere. How do I do this?

EDIT: I have come to understand that you can assert a flat function was called like so:

```js
const myFunc = vi.fn()
myFunc()
expect(myFunc).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

That also means this works:

```js
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'

vi.mock('@vueuse/head')
vi.mocked(useHead).mockImplementation(vi.fn())

describe('myTest', () => {
  useHead({ title: 'foobar' })
  expect(useHead).toBeCalledWith({ title: 'foobar' })
})
```

HOWEVER, I still cannot get it to detect that `useHead()` was called when it is called inside my own composable:

```js
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'
import myComposableThatCallsUseHead from 'path/to/composable'

vi.mock('@vueuse/head')
vi.mocked(useHead).mockImplementation(vi.fn())

describe('myTest', () => {
  myComposableThatCallsUseHead()
  expect(useHead).toBeCalledWith({ title: 'foobar' })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here... The issue is that `useHead` is an auto-import in Nuxt 3 and I was importing it in my tests from the wrong package.

Instead of:

```js
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'
```

use this instead:

```js
import { useHead } from '@unhead/vue'
```

And also:

```js
vi.mock('@unhead/vue')
vi.mocked(useHead).mockImplementation(vi.fn())
```

I hope the Nuxt documentation will be updated to explicitly state what package all these auto-imports come from.

**Edit: Although the above works, an even better approach is to use `mockNuxtImport()`:**

```js
import { mockNuxtImport } from 'nuxt-vitest/utils'

mockNuxtImport('useHead', () => {
  return () => {}
})

// your tests here
```

See [Nuxt Vitest docs for more info](https://nuxt.com/modules/vitest#mocknuxtimport).

Comment: Thank you, saved my time! Although this was enough to make it work: https://github.com/whispeer-me/frontend/commit/cd564530e59d5f95bfbbd1e064798910b99b0ed5